# Combine elements in vector that have the same enum class type

Tags: c++, vector

I have a menu system that takes in external orders from a csv file and also takes in internal orders from the user input. The orders are all stored in the vector `orderQueue`. Each order in the vector has an OrderType and a quantity variable. How do I merge the orders with the same OrderType together so I can get the total quantity of each OrderType?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "CSVReader.h"

CSVReader::CSVReader() 
{

}

std::vector<OrderEntry> CSVReader::readCSV(std::string csvFilename) 
{
    std::vector<OrderEntry> entries; 
    std::ifstream csvFile{csvFilename}; 
    std::string line; 
    
    if (csvFile.is_open()) 
    {
        std::cout << "CSVReader::readCSV file open" << std::endl; 
        while (std::getline(csvFile, line)) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                OrderEntry oe = stringsToOE(tokenise(line, ',')); 
                entries.push_back(oe); 
            } 
            catch (const std::exception& e) 
            { 
                std::cout << "CSVReader::readCSV bad data" << std::endl; 
            } 
        }
    }else
    {
        std::cout << "File not open " << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout<<"CSVReader::readCSV read "<< entries.size() << " entries"  << std::endl;

    return entries; 
}

std::vector<std::string> CSVReader::tokenise(std::string csvLine, char separator) 
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens; 
    signed int start, end; 
    std::string token;

    start = csvLine.find_first_not_of(separator, 0); 
    
    do {
        end = csvLine.find_first_of(separator, start);
        if(start == csvLine.length() || start == end) break;

        if(end >= 0) token = csvLine.substr(start, end - start);
        else token = csvLine.substr(start, csvLine.length() - start);
        tokens.push_back(token);

        start = end + 1;
    }while(end > 0);

    return tokens; 
}

OrderEntry CSVReader::stringsToOE(std::vector<std::string> tokens) 
{
    int qty; 

    if (tokens.size()!= 2) 
    {
        std::cout << "Bad line " << std::endl;
        throw std::exception{};
    }
    try{
        qty = std::stoi(tokens[1]);
    }catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "CSVReader::stringsToOE Bad float! "<< tokens[1]<<std::endl; 
        throw;
    }
    OrderEntry oe{qty,
                  OrderEntry::stringToOrderType(tokens[0])};
    return oe;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "OrderEntry.h"
#include "MerkelMain.h"
#include "OrderFood.h"
#include "CSVReader.h"

MerkelMain::MerkelMain(OrderFood _orders)
: orders (_orders)
{
    
}

MerkelMain::MerkelMain() 
: MerkelMain(OrderFood{ "external_order.csv" })
{

}

void MerkelMain::init()
{
    std::string input;

    while (true)
    {
        printMenu();    
        input = getUserOption();
        processUserOption(input);
    }
}

void MerkelMain::printMenu()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to Restaurant Firebird" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a . Order a plate of chicken rice" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b . Order a plat for wanton noodles" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c . Order a cup of Coffee" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d . Order a cup of Tea" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e . Repeat Order" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f . Exit Menu" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "g . Print All Orders" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Type an option from a-g" << std::endl;
}


std::string MerkelMain::getUserOption()
{
    std::string choice;
    std::cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

int MerkelMain::getQuantity()
{
    int qty;
    std::cin >> qty;
    return qty;
}

void MerkelMain::processUserOption(std::string choice)
{
   std::ofstream internal_File{"internal_order.csv"};
   std::ofstream all_File{ "all_orders.csv" };

   std::endl(std::cout);

   if (choice == "a")
    {
        std::cout << "How many plates of chicken rice would you like to order?" << std::endl;
        OrderType order = OrderType::chickenrice;
        int qty = getQuantity();
        std::endl(std::cout);
        std::cout << "Thank you for your order of " << qty << " plates of Chicken Rice." << std::endl;
        std::endl(std::cout);
        OrderEntry food_order = OrderEntry(qty, order);
        orders.orderQueue.push_back(std::move(food_order));
    }
    if (choice == "b")
    {
        std::cout << "How many plates of wanton noodles would you like to order?" << std::endl;
        OrderType order = OrderType::wantonnoodle;
        int qty = getQuantity();
        std::endl(std::cout);
        std::cout << "Thank you for your order of " << qty << " plates of Wanton Noodles." << std::endl;
        std::endl(std::cout);
        OrderEntry food_order = OrderEntry(qty, order);
        orders.orderQueue.push_back(std::move(food_order));
    }
    if (choice == "c")
    {
        std::cout << "How many cups of Coffee would you like to order?" << std::endl;
        OrderType order = OrderType::coffee;
        int qty = getQuantity();
        std::endl(std::cout);
        std::cout << "Thank you for your order of " << qty << " cups of Coffee." << std::endl;
        OrderEntry food_order = OrderEntry(qty, order);
        orders.orderQueue.push_back(std::move(food_order));
    }
    if (choice == "d")
    {
        std::cout << "How many cups of Tea would you like to order?" << std::endl;
        OrderType order = OrderType::tea;
        int qty = getQuantity();
        std::endl(std::cout);
        std::cout << "Thank you for your order of " << qty << " cups of Tea." << std::endl;
        std::endl(std::cout);
        OrderEntry food_order = OrderEntry(qty, order);
        orders.orderQueue.push_back(std::move(food_order));
    }
    if (choice == "e")
    {
        std::cout << "You have ordered: " << std::endl;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < orders.orderQueue.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::string listOrder = std::to_string(orders.orderQueue[i].qty) + " " + OrderEntry::orderTypeToString(orders.orderQueue[i].orderType);
            std::cout << listOrder << std::endl;
            internal_File << listOrder << std::endl;
        }
        std::endl(std::cout);
    }
    if (choice == "f")
    {
        std::cout << "Thank you and see you again soon." << std::endl;
    }
    if (choice == "g")
    {
        std::cout << "All external and internal orders: " << std::endl;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < orders.orderQueue.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::string listOrder = std::to_string(orders.orderQueue[i].qty) + " " + OrderEntry::orderTypeToString(orders.orderQueue[i].orderType);
            std::cout << listOrder << std::endl;
            all_File << listOrder << std::endl;
        }
        std::endl(std::cout);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use [`std::unordere_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`:

```
#include <map>

std::map<std::string,std::uint64_t> order_map;
string order;
std::uint64_t qty;
order_map[order]+=qty;
```

cheers,
FM.